# Typescript 2 cannot resolve external node module

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typescript2.0

I've been trying to do some prototyping using koa and Typescript2.0.

I've set up a simple project with the following tsconfig.json :

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./bin/",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "jsx": "react",
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "types": [
            "node"
        ]
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

I installed the node definition file via `npm install --save @types/node` and I'm now trying to import a node module with `import Morgan = require('koa-morgan')` but this keeps throwing the error: `error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'koa-morgan'.`
I'm using VScode and I properly updated the tsdk so that's not the issue.

What am I missing?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should either get typings for `koa-morgan` and include them the same way as you did for `node`, or if they are not available and you have time and will - create one yourself.

Otherwise just import then the defaul javascript way:

```
const Morgan = require('koa-morgan');
```

But that will leave you without type checks from typescript aswell

Comment: Right, but I thought the recommended syntax for node modules was import x = require('foo') and I remember using that in a previous project, so why don't that work here?
Also, that requires me having to manually place ///<rerference /> in every file where I use a node module that does not have typings

Comment: If typescript cannot infer type information and verify what you are importing - you cant use that syntax. You do not have to place //<reference> in any of the cases either. If you have typings and proper reference them in tsconfig - typescript will use them, otherwise with old syntax you just work in plain javascript with no typings